# How to check if the certain npm module is globally installed on my machine?

Tags: nodejs, npm

How to check if the some needfull npm module is globally installed on my machine,and if so, what is the version ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check which modules of nodejs or node (snap package) are installed globally run this command:

```
npm -g ls
```

To check if a node module (example *unique-string* module) is installed globally run this command:

```
npm -g ls | grep unique-string
```

Results:

```
│ │ ├─┬ unique-string@1.0.0
```

Comment: This is for all globally installed npm modules which help me too,but, is there a way to check only targeted module?

Comment: Thanks a lot,cant upvote because i am newbie and havent reputation.

Comment: `npm -g ls unique-string` or `npm -g v unique-string` as well.

Comment: That's nice to get verbose output.

Comment: @muru Thank you too,i can only say thanks for now,cant upvote.@karel npm -g ls | grep unique-string  method is exactly what i need.